# MediaStore show Images after deleted from File Manager

Tags: android, android-studio, mediastore

I use MediaStore to get all Images from Android device. Then after I delete some of the Images from File Manager. Followed I use MediaStore again to get Images, and I get all deleted files which is problem.

Why MediaStore returns files that are no longer are on the device(Deleted from device) ?

Code which I am using to retrieve image from MediaStore.

```
Uri uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME};

Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED + " DESC");

String ImagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA));
```

Help to resolve this issue.

Comment: perhaps your images store your personal app folder not in file manager ,once check.

Comment: @BhunnuBaba.... Not personal folder it probably a camera photo.

Answer (score 3):

> Why MediaStore returns files that are no longer are on the device(Deleted from device) ?

Because whatever file manager you used did not do anything to inform the `MediaStore` about the deletion of the files. `MediaStore` will find out eventually, but it may be several hours.

Comment: this is Default file manager and also Gallery not shows all that deleted images.

Comment: @Janak: "this is Default file manager" -- Android does not have a file manager. Your device might have a file manager. And your "Default file manager" is not doing anything to inform the `MediaStore` about the deletion of the files. "Gallery not shows all that deleted images" -- there are thousands of Android device models and hundreds of different pre-installed gallery apps. If I had to guess, the gallery app is detecting that files are missing when it goes to create thumbnails for them, and simply filters those out of what it renders.

Comment: can we do anything to refresh MediaStore like Gallery or FileManager? because File manager also not show that deleted files to.

Comment: @Janak: "because File manager also not show that deleted files to" -- most likely, the file manager is working with the filesystem, not with `MediaStore`. "can we do anything to refresh MediaStore" -- you do not know what was deleted, so, no, you have no good way to refresh the `MediaStore`.

Answer (score 0):

You can rescan Media using below code

```
 MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[]{imagePath}, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
        //something that you want to do
    }
});
```